# Using external functions in a .commands menu

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I am using .commands in my swift application.

I tried to use a function from a different swift file on a button, but it did not work.I know that the function works when referenced from a different file, so the code of the function works.
Here is the code of the file.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

@main
struct Ion_MacOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Visibility") {
                Button("Show") {
                    WebViewModel().docShown = true
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("S")
                Button("Hide") {
                    WebViewModel().hideDoc()
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("H")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the file referenced:

```
import Combine
import WebKit

class WebViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let webView: WKWebView

    private let navigationDelegate: WebViewNavigationDelegate

    init() {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.websiteDataStore = .nonPersistent()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        navigationDelegate = WebViewNavigationDelegate()

        webView.navigationDelegate = navigationDelegate
        setupBindings()
    }

    @Published var urlString: String = ""
    @Published var canGoBack: Bool = false
    @Published var canGoForward: Bool = false
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = false
    @Published var docShown: Bool = true
    @Published var aturl: String = ""
    

    private func setupBindings() {
        webView.publisher(for: \.canGoBack)
            .assign(to: &$canGoBack)

        webView.publisher(for: \.canGoForward)
            .assign(to: &$canGoForward)

        webView.publisher(for: \.isLoading)
            .assign(to: &$isLoading)

    }

    func loadUrl() {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_3_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.4 Safari/605.1.15"
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    func goForward() {
        webView.goForward()
    }

    func goBack() {
        webView.goBack()
    }
    func reloadPage() {
        webView.reload()
    }
    func searchWork(){
        let str = "\(urlString)"
        let replaced = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/search?q=\(replaced)") else {
            return
        }
        webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_3_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.4 Safari/605.1.15"
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    func hideDoc(){
        docShown = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a new instance of your view model and updating it in the button action is pointless since that instance will be removed as soon as the action ends. I am not sure what the right solution is here because it's unclear how you use that view model in other parts of your code.

Comment: It just controls an if statement in ContentView.swift that shows or hides the document

Comment: Read the last sentence again.

Comment: Every time you call “WebViewModel()” it is a different instance, one does not know about the other.

Comment: actually, the function relates to the same variable, but makes it false.